# Is there anyway to log Flash errors on the client side through a browser?

Tags: flash, flash-media-server

Assuming a client won't have the debug version of Flash player installed, is there any way we can log errors that happen on the client side on a browser?

Or at worst, can we somehow log using Flash Media Server?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "flash.external.ExternalInterface" class.

Inside your application use like this,

ExternalInterface.call("console.log","your message");

This will log your message in browser's console. (ie, Console of developer tools in browser)

Comment: But then,those messages can't be recovered, right? Say, once the browser is closed?

Comment: If you want to save the errors into a file, You can use ajax in combination with ExternalInterface call. You need to have a javascript method in your html page namely logErrors. `function logErrors(message) { //use ajax calls here to save the error into a file in your server }` Then you need to use this inside your flash, `ExternalInterface.call("logErrors","your message");` Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since in comment the formatting is not proper I posted as new answer.

If you want to save the errors into a file, You can use ajax in combination with ExternalInterface call.
 You need to have a javascript method in your html page namely logErrors.

function logErrors(message)
{

//use ajax calls here to save the error into a file in your server

}

Then you need to use this inside your flash,

`ExternalInterface.call("logErrors","your message");`

Hope this will help you.